# Is my solution correct? (trigonometry)

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$$2\cos x\left(\cos x-\sqrt{8}\tan x\right)<5$$

After expanding I get $2\sin^2 x+4\sqrt{2}\sin x-5>0$. I then factorized $(2\sin x+3\sqrt{2})(2\sin x+\sqrt{2})>0$. The first one is always positive so $\sin x>\sin(-\pi/4)$. How to continue?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).
Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin x>-\sqrt{2}/2$ and you have $\sin(-\pi/4)=\sin(5\pi/4)=-\sqrt{2}/2$. The big arc between $-\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ is the solution :
$$\left[\frac{-\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}\right]~~~\text{(mod }2\pi\text{)}$$
Another way to denote this solution is 
$$\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left[\frac{-\pi}{4}+2n\pi, \frac{5\pi}{4}+2n\pi\right]$$